# Usage of "как бы"

Tags: значения, словоупотребление, conjunctions

> Но когда пришли братья Его, тогда и Он пришел на праздник не явно, а как бы тайно.

- Whats *как бы* doing in this sentence (as in function)?
- Would it be possible to leave it out, without changing the meaning? And/Or if it would be let out, what would be changed by it?
- What would be a typical example for when to use *как бы*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be thrown away if it is used as "parasite" word (which is quite common nowadays - meaning is similar to "kinda" or "like"). But not in this case.

Efremova dictionary states that **Как бы**  is used as:

> I союз
>   1.
>   Употребляется при присоединении члена предложения со значением условно-предположительного сравнения, соответствуя по значению сл.: как будто.
>
> 2.
>   Употребляется при присоединении члена предложения или придаточной части сложноподчиненного предложения со значением сравнения (которое представляется недостоверным), соответствуя по значению сл.: как бы, будто бы, как если бы.
>
> II част.
>     Употребляется при выражении предположительности, условности высказывания, соответствуя по значению сл.: будто, будто бы.

I think in your example it is conjunction that means "as if". So the meaning here is that "He" did not visit the celebration officially, but he did come without drawing attention to his presence. Though he did not really made a secret from his coming. Omitting "как бы"  here would mean that he did tried to be unnoticed.

As you can see from the Efremova citation there are 2 more other ways of using "как бы".

---

By the way, when speaking on religious texts they cannot be taken as typical examples of usage. As Yellow Sky stated, the text of Bible is not changed for centuries and therefore outdated in terms of modern language use.

Comment: Could you point out (even) more clearly the difference between *...не явно, а тайно.* and *...не явно, а как бы тайно*. I'm not yet getting the nuance of it.

Comment: When you say "не тихо, а громко" you just mean "громко". When you say "не тихо, а как бы громко" you mean that it is not really so loud, but louder than needed.

Comment: Okay, think I got it.

Comment: Concerning the edit: to me it seems in the given sentence it doesn't make much difference, does it?

Comment: I would translate it as "somewhat", i.e. "somewhat secretly".

Comment: @aksakal: .. and that would be in Russian how?

Comment: @embert, "как бы тайно" ~ "somewhat secretly"

Comment: @aksakal: ah okay. I thought it's about my most recent comment, cause I was wondering whether the sentence would be somehow different expressed in Russian nowadays e. g. in a report, since to me it sounds like the origin of this sentence (synodal) does not matter here.

Comment: @embert, I also do not think that the origin matters here, but I'm not a theologist and could be missing something.

Answer (score 5):

Your quote is from the Gospel of John 7:10. In correspondence with the Russian `как бы` the Latin Biblia Sacra Vulgata has `quasi`, the English King James Bible has `as it were`. The idea of `как бы` is 'kind of', 'as if'.

And no, it cannot be left out, it's the Bible, long ago every word in it became a part of the foundation of the modern culture. And this very John in Revelation 22:19 says it out right:

> And if any man shall take away from the words of the book of this prophecy, God shall take away his part out of the book of life, and out of the holy city, and from the things which are written in this book.

Comment: +1 for the Bible reference, but I think your interpretation of John's statement is not applicable to translations. John's didn't mean to say that there can only be one Russian translation of the Bible. His statement concerns the original words of God, which were spoken in some other language (Aramaic?).

Comment: В. Н. Кузнецова, author of the modern translation of the New Testament, most probably does not share your confidence that _как бы_ can’t be left out. In her translation John 7:10 looks like ‘_Но после того, как Его братья ушли на праздник, Иисус тоже пошел туда, только не открыто, а тайно_’.

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov - But В. Н. Кузнецова didn't actually leave it out, she substituted it for a phrase with a very similar meaning. Note that the OP didn't ask about the possibility of substituting the phrase, that's why I didn't write anything about that.

Comment: @Aksakal - The [original text](http://azbyka.ru/biblia/?Jn.7&crgl) of the Gospel of John was in Koine Greek: "οὐ φανερῶς ἀλλὰ **ὡς** ἐν κρυπτῷ" (not openly but **like** in secret), the Church Slavonic canonical text translates the Greek phrase practically word-for-word: "не явѣ, но **яко** тай" (not openly but **like** secretly), and the Synodal Translation quoted by the OP also translates the original Greek phrase the same way.

Comment: Actually this is kind of the word that can _always_ be left out, and Bible-reference changes nothing. Bible is also a text, and actually not very well-written.

Comment: @Viridianus - How well or how badly the Bible is written set aside, will you give a reason why a word or a phrase should be left out from a text? Do you know that you, me, our Earth, our Sun, everything in the world is also a part of the text? Our Universe is a text, do you realize that? If the Sun, you, and me are left out, the text will change _a bit_, won't it? Moreover, it will become a _different_ text. The same will happen with the Bible text if you leave out something from it. So why should one substitute one text with another one?

Comment: @YellowSky one should know the difference between 1)nouns, adjectives, verbs, numerals, adverbs, predicatives, and pronouns ("знаменательные части речи"); 2)prepositions and conjunctions; 3)meaningful particles; 4)less meaningful particles and interjections. "Как бы" is from the fourth group.

Answer (score 1):

"как бы" can be translated as "as if" or "sort of".

Your example can be trnaslated as "...He came to the celebration not openly, but as if secretly".

As for a typical example, here is one from Tutchev:

> Люблю грозу в начале мая,
>
> Когда весенний, первый гром,
>
> **Как бы** резвяся и играя,
>
> Грохочет в небе голубом.